# How to retrieve data from view bag in jquery(inside the view) in c#, mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, list, viewbag

I'm sending a `List` using `ViewBag` to the view like this.

```
List<RegionSearch> rs = searchregionArray.Select(sr => new RegionSearch()
{
    region = (string)sr["AREA/DEST"],

}).ToList();

var filteredRegion = rs.Select(k => k.region).Distinct();

//testing 
ViewBag.checking = rs;
```

now I want to get it in `<script></script>` .how can I do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :-

```
<script>
   var jsonList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Convert(ViewBag.checking))'
   var jsList = JSON.parse(jsonList);
   console.log(jsList);
</script>
```

**NOTE :-** Although not a good idea sending whole list from controller to view inside `ViewBag` instead use `ViewModel`.

Comment: job done.but `Json.Convert` is not in its reference. then I used `Json.Encode` then it worked.do you have an idea to read it's `objects` and `find` specific object

Comment: @bill..ya..but I won't be able to write answer in comments section.I think [this](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc836466(v=vs.94).aspx) post will work for you.

Comment: could you please look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355390/how-to-find-specific-objects-and-put-them-in-to-and-array-in-javascript
@Kartikeya Khosla