# how to find specific objects and put them in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

I have this result in my script

```
'[{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Havana, Cuba"},{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Havana, Cuba"},{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Montego Bay, Jamaica"},{"region":"NCA","depprt":"Montego Bay, Jamaica"}]'
```

this is the code to get it.

```
var jsonList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chk))'
        var jsList = JSON.stringify(jsonList);
```

for `jsList` I got above result.now I want to get all `depprt` where `region` is equal to `NCA`.how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [.filter()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) method for this.

```
var ncaList = jsonList.filter(function(obj){ return obj.region == "NCA"; });
```

Comment: nice it works.now how can I get the `depprt` at the same time and avoid duplicates with this.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple. Iterate over the `jList` array and see if the `region` property matches your condition or not then append the item to your filtered array.

```
var filtered = [];
jList.forEach(function(item) {
   if(item.region == 'NCA') {
      filtered.push(item);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over it:

```
var filteredDepprts = [];
jsList.forEach(function(element){
  if(element.region == 'NCA'){
    filteredList.push(element.depprt); //or element if you want to push the full object
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON.stringify method converts a JavaScript value to a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

When you want to convert a JSON string to a JavaScript value, use JSON.parse

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

```
var jsonList = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.chk))'
var jsList = JSON.parse(jsonList);
```

*Using single quotes around your @Html.Raw, creates a string and not a JavaScript value. The filter method does not work on strings*

Eventually you could use Array.prototype.filter Filter out each element in array, that matches your criteria.

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

Try map:

```
var obj= [];
for (i in jsonList) {
  if (jsonList[i].region == "NCA") { obj.push(jsonList[i])};
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pd6hvn78/